# How To Load CSV file in Neo4j in linux Machine

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to load the CSV file in to Neo4j. But it was throwing error like this

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/home/trainings/Desktop/neo4j-community-3.0.6/import/home/trainings/Desktop/neo4j_module_datasets/terrorist_data_subset.csv
```

I tried changing the neo4j.conf file. I have changed

```
dbms.directories.import=import
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

even though im facing the error.[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a little bit old post but I would like to share answer.

On Ubuntu linux neo4j version 3.2.2 open the conf from `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf`.

Find the line `dbms.directories.import`. Modify this path to `change the default import location` or `comment out to load using the absolute path` from `'/`'.

Then add the file path in query as below.

`LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///artists.csv' AS line CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInt(line[2])})`

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this config line: `dbms.directories.import=import`.

Comment: I did it . But no Use - Jeanie

Answer (score 0):

Just by placing the .CSV in to Import folder we can able to load the data into Neo4j

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out the `dbms.directories.import=import` (located within `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf`), this allows system-wide access from neo4j **dangerous**, but maybe fine if it is only run on a personal machine.

To enable changes you must then kill all neo4j processes and restart the server `pkill -u neo4j ; sudo neo4j start`. When loading you should get something similar to:

```
Active database: graph.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /var/lib/neo4j
  config:       /etc/neo4j
  logs:         /var/log/neo4j
  plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
  import:       NOT SET
  data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
  certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /var/run/neo4j
```

Note the `NOT SET` in the `import` row.